# Relational database phpmyadmin varchars instead of IDs

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create relational database. I have 2 columns in 2 tables that I would like to connect, both are `varchars`.

Both relations are one to many. One column `Patch_No` and second `Champion`. I've added to both indexes.

First table:
[image]

Second Table:
[image]

Here is also relational view: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LylHE.png

Comment: Do you mean that the `Patch_No` and `Champion` columns form a composite key?

Comment: Yes, I'm new to the whole relational database world it's pretty much my first one